# Symfony - Delivery of old and new updated object for multiple endpoints

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am currently working on a small api project and I would like to do the following, I am stuck there:

The goal is: you have the possibility to update an entry and if this is the case, the old version of the edited entry object will be delivered via the first endpoint. The new version of the edited entry object is delivered via the second endpoint.

1. endpoint: entries with the status published are delivered .. works!!
2. endpoint: all entries are delivered .. works!!
3. endpoint: entry {id} is returned (object of an entry) .. works!!

**Update Controller:**

```
public function update(string $id, FormRequest $request)
    {
        $article = $this->getArticle($id);

        if ($request->handle(ArticleType::class, $article)) {
            /** @var Article $data */
            $data = $request->getValidData();
            $this->service->update();
            return $data;
        }
        return $request->getForm();
    }
```

**Service:**

```
public function update(): void
    {
        $this->manager->flush();
    }
```

My idea was to clone the old object during the update process, but it didn't work because I don't know what to do with the cloned object. Currently the edited object is always delivered without distinction between old and new, let alone a clone.

I don't know, maybe you have an idea that could help me out a bit.. that'd be great :)

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to version your entity? [Doctrine extensions](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) (the [Loggable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/loggable.md)) _could_ help with that, but it might be too much for your case. Maybe just caching the old version, but be careful with ttl and cache clearing.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class OldArticle that extends Article and is mapped to a separate table in the db.
When the article is updated, create a new OldArticle(Article article), persist and flush
You can then create a new endpoint that return the old article